# Aggregate group with multi-level columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a grouped DataFrame which i want to aggregate with a dictionary of functions which should map to certain columns. For single-level columns this is straightforward with `groups.agg({'colname': <function>})`. I am struggling however to get this working with multi-level columns, from which i only want to refer to a single level.

Here is an example.

Lets make some sample data:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

lev1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
lev2 = list('abc')

n = 6

df = pd.DataFrame({k: np.random.randn(n) for k in itertools.product(lev1,lev2)}, 
                  index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2015-01-01', periods=n, freq='11D'))
```

That looks like:

```
             bar               baz               foo            
               a     b     c     a     b     c     a     b     c
2015-01-01 -1.11  2.12 -1.00  0.18  0.14  1.24  0.73  0.06  3.66
2015-01-12 -1.43  0.75  0.38  0.04 -0.33 -0.42  1.00 -1.63 -1.35
2015-01-23  0.01 -1.70 -1.39  0.59 -1.10 -1.17 -1.51 -0.54 -1.11
2015-02-03  0.93  0.70 -0.12  1.07 -0.97 -0.45 -0.19  0.11 -0.79
2015-02-14  0.30  0.49  0.60 -0.28 -0.38  1.11  0.15  0.78 -0.58
2015-02-25 -0.26  0.51  0.82  0.05 -1.45  0.14  0.53 -0.33 -1.35
```

And grouping by month with:

```
groups = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('MS'))
```

Define some functions based on the top-level in the columns:

```
funcs = {'bar': np.sum, 'baz': np.mean, 'foo': np.min}
```

However, doing `groups.agg(funcs)` results in a KeyError, because it expects a key for each level, which makes sense.

This does work for example:

```
groups.agg({('bar', 'a'): np.mean})

                 bar
                   a
2015-01-01 -0.845554
2015-02-01  0.324897
```

But i don't want to specify each key on the second level. So I'm looking for something which would work like:

```
groups.agg({('bar', slice(None)): np.mean})
```

But that doesn't work of course since a `slice` is not hashable, and therefore cant be put in a dictionary.

A workaround would be:

```
def multifunc(group):

    func = funcs[group.name[0]]        
    return func(group)

groups.agg(multifunc)
```

But that is not very readable nor does it seem "Pandonic" to me. Also it doesnt allow for multiple functions on the same column as the `agg` function does. There must a better/standard way of performing such a task, it cant be very uncommon.

Comment: I opened an issue to discuss if we want to make this easier: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9585 But, I am not sure what would be the best interface. I suppose `{'bar': np.sum, 'baz': np.mean, 'foo': np.min}` could just work? Feel free to chime in!

Comment: Thanks Joris! It would certainly be interesting to see the discussion about that. There are always workarounds, as Unutbu showed. But that means a step back from the Pandas interface, and the easy interface is a large part of what makes Pandas so amazing to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a short-cut for this. Fortunately, it is not too hard to build the desired dict explicitly:

```
result = groups.agg(
    {(k1, k2): funcs[k1] for k1, k2 in itertools.product(lev1,lev2)})
```

---

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lev1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
lev2 = list('abc')

n = 6

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {k: np.random.randn(n) for k in itertools.product(lev1,lev2)}, 
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2015-01-01', periods=n, freq='11D'))
groups = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('MS'))
funcs = {'bar': np.sum, 'baz': np.mean, 'foo': np.min}
result = groups.agg(
    {(k1, k2): funcs[k1] for k1, k2 in itertools.product(lev1,lev2)})
result = result.sortlevel(axis=1)
print(result)
```

yields

```
                 bar                           baz                      \
                   a         b         c         a         b         c   
2015-01-01 -2.144890  1.075044  1.038169 -0.460649 -0.309966 -0.211147   
2015-02-01  1.313744  0.247171  1.049129 -0.174827 -0.437982 -0.196427   

                 foo                      
                   a         b         c  
2015-01-01 -1.358973 -1.846916 -0.896234  
2015-02-01 -1.354953 -0.699607  0.288214
```